# Sufficient conditions for bounded output of an explicit linear multi-step method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

The system:
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) &= f(x(t))\\
x(t_0) &= x_0
\end{align}
is being solved by an explicit linear multi-step method (assume perfect initialization):
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{x}_{n+s} = \sum_{j=0}^{s-1}a_j\widetilde{x}_{n+j} + h\sum_{j=0}^{s-1}b_jf(\widetilde{x}_{n+j})
\end{equation}
What are sufficient conditions that there exist constants $C, H > 0$ such that for all $h \in [0, H)$ the numerical solution of the method is bounded
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{x}_n < C
\end{equation}
in the interval $t_0 \leqslant t_0 + nh \leqslant t_{end}$.

---

Assumption:

The above method is zero-stable if the roots of the polynomial:
\begin{equation}
\psi(u) = u^s -\sum_{j=0}^{s-1}a_ju^j
\end{equation}
are within a closed unit disk and the roots on the unit circle are simple.
Zero-stability is a sufficient condition for the above method to give a bounded input in the sense stated above.

---

My thoughts:

Zero-stability is a necessary condition for the above system to be convergent (see e.g. Stoer, Bulirsch - Introduction to Numerical Analysis (2002)).
This can be shown by choosing an example system $\dot{x} = 0$. The same proof can be made to show that zero-stability is a necessary for the existence of the above bounds.

Zero-stability and consistency of a method are sufficient conditions for convergence of that method.
The solution $x(t)$ is differentiable on the whole interval.
Differentiable functions are bounded on the closed interval.
If the method is convergent than it has a bounded error for infinitesimally small step sizes.
This means convergence is sufficient for the bounded output of the method.

Can this condition be relaxed?
My intuition tells me that zero-stability without consistency is enough for the method to give a bounded output.
Is this intuition correct and can it be proven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to try to answer my own question.
Zero-stability and [Lipschitz continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) of $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are enough to prove the existence of the bounds.

---

The method described in the question can be described with the help of a [companion matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178814/understanding-why-the-roots-of-homogeneous-difference-equation-must-be-eigenvalu):
\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\widetilde{x}_{n+s}\\
\widetilde{x}_{n+s-1}\\
\vdots\\
\widetilde{x}_{n+2}\\
\widetilde{x}_{n+1}
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
a_{s-1} & a_{s-2} & \dots & a_1 & a_{0}\\
1       & 0       & \dots &  0  & 0 \\
0       & 1       & \ddots& \vdots   & 0 \\
\vdots  & \ddots  & \ddots& 0 &\vdots\\
0       & \dots   & 0     & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\widetilde{x}_{n+s-1}\\
\widetilde{x}_{n+s-2}\\
\vdots\\
\widetilde{x}_{n+1}\\
\widetilde{x}_{n}
\end{array}\right]
+
h
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
b_{s-1} & b_{s-2} & \dots & b_1 & b_{0}\\
0       & 0       & \dots &  0  & 0 \\
0       & 0       & \ddots& \vdots   & 0 \\
\vdots  & \ddots  & \ddots& 0 &\vdots\\
0       & \dots   & 0     & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
f(\widetilde{x}_{n+s-1})\\
f(\widetilde{x}_{n+s-2})\\
\vdots\\
f(\widetilde{x}_{n+1})\\
f(\widetilde{x}_{n})
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
or using a matrix notation:
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_{n} = \mathbf{A}\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_{n-1} + h\mathbf{B}\mathbf{f}(\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_{n-1})
\end{equation}
Lipschitz continuity of a function implies that the function has a [linear growth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227314/relation-between-lipschitz-condition-and-linear-growth-condition):
\begin{equation}
\lvert f(\widetilde{x})\rvert \leqslant M + L \lvert \widetilde{x}\rvert
\end{equation}
where $M, L >0$.
This means that the previous difference equation can be rewritten to:
\begin{equation}
\lVert\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_{n}\rVert \leqslant \lVert\mathbf{A}\rVert\lVert\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_{n-1}\rVert + h\lVert\mathbf{B}\rVert(M\mathbf{1} + L\lVert\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_{n-1}\rVert)
\end{equation}
A consequence of proposition 4. in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424458/is-spectral-radius-operator-norm-for-a-positive-valued-matrix) for a zero-stable method there exists a norm for which:
\begin{equation}
\lVert\mathbf{A}\rVert = \rho(\mathbf{A}) \leqslant 1
\end{equation}
After introducing the previous inequality and substitution of constants $C = \lVert\mathbf{B}\rVert L$ and $D = \lVert\mathbf{B}\rVert M\lVert\mathbf{1}\rVert$ the following inequality is obtained:
\begin{equation}
\lVert\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_{n}\rVert \leqslant (1 + hC)\lVert\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_{n-1}\rVert + hD
\end{equation}
By the use Taylor series of the exponential function and the use of induction:
\begin{equation}
\lVert\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_{n}\rVert \leqslant e^{Ch}\lVert\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_{n-1}\rVert + hD \leqslant
e^{nCh}\lVert\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_0\rVert + hD \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{kCh}
\leqslant
e^{nCh}\lVert\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_0\rVert + nhD e^{nCh}
\end{equation}
Since the number of of samples on the closed interval is $n = \frac{t_{end}-t_0}{h}$ (round-off is ignored for simplicity):
\begin{equation}
\lVert\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_{n}\rVert \leqslant 
e^{C(t_{end}-t_0)}\lVert\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_0\rVert + D(t_{end}-t_0)e^{C(t_{end}-t_0)}
\end{equation}
Since there exists a constant for which $\lVert\widetilde{\mathbf{x}}_{n}\rVert$ the statement is proved.